# Regex in Notepad++ with Negative Lookahead with Question Mark Operator

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, square-bracket

I'm trying to find a way to replace square brackets into apostrophes for some subtitle files, but only for cases when these square brackets do not contain a whole sentence having the square brackets at the beginning & end of the line.

These lines would have square brackets changed into apostrophes:

```
[que] vão levar [vocês]
ao [limite].
```

While these would not:

```
[Vamos começar]
[com algo simples.]
```

I came up with the following regex command

```
(?!^\[.*?\]$)(\[.*?\])
```

That uses negative lookahead to find lines starting with `[` and ending with `]`, while using the inside question mark character `?` as an operator to prevent selection of line with extra square brackets.

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: If my answer worked for you please consider ticking the grey mark to the left of my answer to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You may match the lines that start with `[` and end with `]` and have no `[` and `]` and capture into Group 1, and only match other `[` and `]` and replace using  a *conditional* replacement pattern:

Find what: `^(\[[^][\r\n]*\])$|[][]`
Replace with: `(?1$1:')`

**Search pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `(\[[^][\r\n]*\])` - Group 1 capturing a `[`, then 0 or more characters other than `]`, `[`, `\r` or `\n` and then `]` at the...
- `$` - end of line
- `|` -  or
- `[][]` - a `[` or `]`

**Replacement pattern details**:

- `(?1` - Did the Group 1 match? If yes,

  - `$1` - use the Group 1 contents
  - `:`  - or
  - `'` - a single apostrophe
- `)`  - end of the conditional pattern.

[image]

Comment: That really did it! Thank you! On the other hand, was there a reason for the inside "?"  Question Mark character not function as an operator inside the Negative Lookahead block?

Comment: Well, it is again a very frequent case when we need to match and capture what we need to keep, and only match what we do not need. See [**The Greatest Regex Trick Ever**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick).